# A package made for lower than Hydro(catkin) distribution, can be used in Hydro?

Tags: roomba, erratic, ros-hydro, ros-electric, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to simulate any robot on Gazebo and stage for understanding both simulators.. But most of the tutorials/packages I found is for Groovy, fuerte ,Electric of Diamondback. Can I use these ?

Or I install multiple ROs distributions for testing them ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192679/a-package-made-for-lower-than-hydro(catkin)-distribution,-can-be-used-in-hydro-??/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2014-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [REP 3 - Target Platforms](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) you can install fuerte, groovy and hydro simultaneously on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine, so that is probably a good compromise for quickly trying things out. A good alternative (at least for Stage) might be virtual machines. With Gazebo, that often does not work very well due to graphics driver related issues, however.

You can try to run software only documented for use with certain ROS releases and sometimes this will work without problems, but there´s always the possibility that things don´t work out due to API changes and such.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2014-09-15**:
Thank you so much. I am doing the same now.